# Do users incur any charges for receiving push notifications on iPhones, even if indirectly?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

I was always under the impression there is no charge associated with using push notifications but this suggests otherwise:

http://mashable.com/2013/07/03/mobile-data-travel/

If a user receives a push notification, especially when in a roaming situation, is there a charge associated with that, even if indirectly as a consequence of the push bumping up the amount of data they have used and thus potentially incurring data overage charges?

Comment: Push => Data => roaming => Fees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push notifications will mean charges are incurred if you ever pay for data. Clearly, most push notifications are very small transmissions, but they almost always use data connection instead of WiFi so if you had thousands of pushes, it might be the bit of data that exceeds your quota and racks up more cost. Also when roaming, all data might be metered a la carte, so you would in essence pay for each notification you received while roaming.

---

As outlined in the comment by Matthieu.

Push notifications are data.  If you are "roaming" (ie. outside the country where you have your service contract with your mobile service provider) you will incur charges.

---

Having said that there are plans which allow for free data roaming globally.  Such as the T-Mobile plans available in the US. This has something to do with the fact that T-Mobile is Deutsche Telecom.  On such a plan there will be no charges.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Deesbek's answer, you can of course [turn off data cellular data](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4146) in the Settings app:

[image: iOS Cellular Data Settings]